# How can I do the mean of n tensors? Sum them and divide the result by N. Getting a tensor with the same shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Python 3.7.7. and Tensorflow 2.1.0.

I'm newbie.

I have N tensors with shape `(1, 12, 12, 512)` and I want to sum each array to get a tensor with the same shape, `(1, 12, 12, 512)`. And then, divide it by N.

These tensors are the output from an encoder with this summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 200, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      1664      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      102464    
_________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 100, 100, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      55392     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      83040     
_________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 50, 50, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       110720    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 25, 25, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       1048832   
_________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 12, 12, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
=================================================================
Total params: 5,384,832
Trainable params: 5,384,832
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The code to get the enconder and the output is this:

```
u_net: Model = utils.get_unet_uncompiled(img_shape = (200, 200, 1))

encoder = Model(inputs=u_net.layers[0].input, outputs=u_net.layers[14].output, name='encoder')

print(encoder.summary())

brain_img = dataset[:, 0, :][28][:, :, 0]

b = np.expand_dims(brain_img, axis=0)
x = np.expand_dims(b, axis=-1)


# Input image must have the same shape than U-Net.
y = encoder(x)

print("Y shape: ", y.shape)
print("Y type: ", type(y))
```

And the print output is:

```
Y shape:  (1, 12, 12, 512)
Y type:  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

I've been searching but I have only found [tf.math.reduce_mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean) and I think it doesn't do what I want to do.

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**:

I think I can use [tf.math.add_n](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add_n) to sum all the tensors and then divide the result tensor by N. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're just looking for the mean as per axis 0?

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform((100, 12, 12, 512), 0, 1, dtype=tf.int32)

tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0, keepdims=True)
```

Shape of result:

```
TensorShape([1, 12, 12, 512])
```

If you are dealing with a list of tensors of shape `(1, 12, 12, 512)`, it's the same:

```
x = [tf.random.uniform((1, 12, 12, 512), 0, 1, dtype=tf.int32) for i in range(10)]

tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0)
```

```
TensorShape([1, 12, 12, 512])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your answer. I will have `(1, 12, 12, 512)` + `(1, 12, 12, 512)` + `(1, 12, 12, 512)` + `(1, 12, 12, 512)` + `...` + `(1, 12, 12, 512)`. I wont have `(100, 12, 12, 512)`. Do I have to convert the N tensors to `(100, 12, 12, 512)`? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how your tensors are? Like, different variables of shape `(1, 12, 12, 512)`? Is this a list? It's the same operation no matter what. See update.

Comment: Are the `B` shape and `x` shape important? I still can't see where you have a collection of tensors with shape `(1, 12, 12, 512)`. I see that you have one assigned to `y` but that's it. Feel free to generate data with `tf.random.normal` or Numpy

Comment: This is only an example about what these tensors are. They have the same type as `y` and the same `shape` as `y`, but I only show you one as an example. `B` and `x` are not important. Maybe your update works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well let me know.